# Why is the voltage rising when I expect a voltage drop in my model?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simulink-library

Part of model

[image: 1]

[matlab model pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ry6NrZYUXpGXL74D_v5u0wUHlVl6Xo6J/view?usp=share_link)

In the model, I have 4 blocks each existing with 3 homes and I am feeding homes with a 3-phase Voltage source, on the ways to homes there are resistors and inductors so I  expect voltage drops on lines. 1. and 3. phase as expected I have a voltage drop but in the 2. phase I am seeing a voltage rise which is not normal while I am having those resistors on the line.

Comment: Are you using the RMS block or the CRMS blocks?

Comment: It is CRMS. @picchiolu

Comment: You're highlighting just the voltage sensor readings, but what are the sinusoidal current-source-looking things near the top rail of your diagram? The diagram looks almost like the [piecewise linear current source](https://www.mathworks.com/help/sps/ref/piecewiselinearcurrentsource.html) but I can't find a direct comparison in my brief search online. Capacitors try to maintain constant voltage; the inductors you've got try to maintain constant current. If you're doing something with the current then you're going to get voltage swings in the inductors as they try to regulate the current swings.

Comment: but the point is, why in the first and third phases we can see voltage drop while we see voltage rise in the second phase it doesn't make sense.